# Could not find or load main class on linux

Tags: java, linux

I've a standalone application that have the following files:

- main.jar  : the main jar file
- lib/*.jar : all dependencies

Under windows, I run the following command with success:

> java -cp "main.jar;lib/*" com.ca.Main

No problem the application runs fine. However, on linux operating system, the command fails with the following message:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.ca.Main

If I run

```
java -cp "main.jar" com.ca.Main
```

JAVA finds the main class but not the dependencies located in lib/

Any idea of what's wrong with linux ? Is there something to do specific to linux ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The separator is `:` instead of `;` in linux. So you need to do `java -cp "main.jar:lib/*" com.ca.Main`.